# Different texts in various pages in footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
\ding{43} Next Page % Right Footer in First Page
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushright}
\ding{43} Next Page % Right Footer in Next Pages, 2. 3. 4. ... pages
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushright}
Check your answers \ding{110} % Right Footer in Last Page
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Except in last page, I want to write in right footer **Next Page**. In last page, I want to write in right footer **Check your answers**. Like multiple choice test pages. *I am sorry for my English.*

Answer (score 4):

In the first LaTeX run, the number of pages is usually not yet known.
You have already loaded package `lastpage`. It sets a reference `LastPage`, which can be used in the following LaTeX runs to get the page number of the last page, when setting the page footer. Package `refcount` helps to get the page number of the reference `LastPage` as number.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
  \refused{LastPage}%
  \ifnum\getrefbykeydefault{LastPage}{page}{0}=0 %
    \ding{43} Maybe next page/Check your answers%
  \else
    \ifnum\getrefbykeydefault{LastPage}{page}{0}=\value{page}%
      Check your answers \ding{110}%
    \else
      \ding{43} Next page%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]\newpage
  \lipsum[2]\newpage
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Result after first LaTeX run:

> [image: Result after first LaTeX run]

Result after second and final LaTeX run,
Page 1 and 2:

> [image: Result, final LaTeX run, page 1 and 2]

Last page 3:

> [image: Result, final LaTeX run, final page 3]

Comment: what's the thing that's overprinted on the "M" in "Maybe"?

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Thanks for noticing, it's a collision with the page number (`\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}`). I have now moved the page number to the left (`\fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}`).

Answer (score 2):

After you define the contents of header/footer you have to load the `fancy` page style.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\rfoot{\ding{43} Next Page} % other options are \cfoot{} \lfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % to remove the ruler on header

\begin{document}\pagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1-30] % dummy text

\rfoot{Check your answers \ding{110}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect working. @Sigur.

Comment: @Özgür, you can find many other tools in the user guide: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250018/different-texts-in-odd-and-even-pages-in-footer Second question @Sigur

Comment: This will work unless the last page is already finished before the final `\rfoot` is called.