# Different texts in odd and even pages in footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\checkoddpage 
\ifoddpage
\rfoot{\ding{43} Next Page} %Odd Pages
\else
\rfoot{\ding{43} Side Page} % Even Pages
\fi

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % to remove the ruler on header

\begin{document}\pagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1-30] % dummy text

\rfoot{Check your answers \ding{110}}
\end{document}
```

It does't work. All pages are writting **Next Page**. What do I?

Related to: [Different texts in various pages in footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250015/different-texts-in-various-pages-in-footer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should use `twoside` in the options:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
   ```
2. Use the provided mechanism by `fancyhdr`:

   ```
       \fancyfoot[RO]{\ding{43} Next Page} %Odd Pages
       \fancyfoot[LE]{\ding{43} Side Page} % Even Pages
   ```

Your `ifoddpage` is executed just once in the preamble, so it is basically run with the page number set to 1 and executes the first `\rfoot` only.

So your MWE can be changed to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\fancyfoot[RO]{\ding{43} Next Page} %Odd Pages
\fancyfoot[LE]{\ding{43} Side Page} % Even Pages

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % to remove the ruler on header

\begin{document}\pagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1-30] % dummy text

\rfoot{Check your answers \ding{110}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `twoside` is default for `book`.

Comment: Perfect working, @Rmano.